# Empty filter results gives #VALUE! error

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I've been working on this project where I need to consolidate data from two other sheets within the spreadsheet and filter the result for easy viewing. But I realized the problem when the filter gives no result there will be a #VALUE! error. The error isn't solved even when I have used IFERROR.

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bb5EW4aCxHm0wpHmLHH1ojZLDN1sI-orj2a-BZGR7E0/edit?usp=sharing) to the sample of the Google Spreadsheets.

There are two classes and I wish to filter out those who passed in the class and populate the table in the collated sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
=query({Class1!A2:C; Class2!A2:C}, "where Col3 = 'pass'")
```

(change the sheet names and ranges to suit !).

(Also check the formula I entered in A1 of sheet 'JP')